# How to force LWP::UserAgent to make a request only once to a Basic Authentication Scheme

Tags: perl, basic-authentication, lwp-useragent

When I use [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) to make an [Authenticated request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#basic_authentication_scheme) there are `two` requests made to my server.

The [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#request) says:

> The request method will process redirects and authentication responses transparently. This means that it may actually send several simple requests via the "simple_request" in LWP::UserAgent method.

I know I can use [authorization_basic](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Headers#$h-%3Eauthorization_basic) to add `Authorization` header.

```perl
$req->authorization_basic('user', 'pass');
```

But is there any way to make `just one` request using only `LWP::UserAgent`?

I tried to create a [Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response) with `401` code to pass as the previous argument but [simple_request is called before this](https://github.com/libwww-perl/libwww-perl/blob/master/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm#L300-L303).

**Minimal Reproducible Example:**

server.pl

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTTP::Daemon;
use HTTP::Status;

my $server = HTTP::Daemon->new(LocalAddr => '127.0.0.1', LocalPort => 9999) or die;

print "Contact URL: ", $server->url, "\n";
while (my $connection = $server->accept) {
    while (my $request = $connection->get_request) {
        print $request->as_string;
        unless( $request->header( 'Authorization' ) ) {
            $connection->send_response( make_challenge() )
            }
        else {
            $connection->send_response( make_response() )
            }
        }
    $connection->close;
    }

sub make_challenge {
    my $response = HTTP::Response->new(
        401 => 'Authorization Required',
        [ 'WWW-Authenticate' => 'Basic realm="Test-Realm"' ],
         );
    }

sub make_response {
    my $response = HTTP::Response->new(
        200 => 'Huzzah!',
        [ 'Content-type' => 'text/plain' ],
         );

    $response->message( 'Huzzah!' );
    }
```

client.pl

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                             

use strict;                                                                     
use warnings;                                                                   
use LWP;                                                                        

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new('Mozilla');
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://127.0.0.1:9999/');                                        
$ua->credentials("127.0.0.1:9999", "Test-Realm", 'user_name', 'some_pass');                       
my $res = $ua->request($req);               

print $res->content;
```

**Output:**

Run Server:

```sh
$ perl server.pl
Contact URL: http://127.0.0.1:9999/
```

Run Client:

```sh
$ perl client.pl
HTTP/1.1 Huzzah! 
Date: Tue, 29 Mar 2022 17:39:53 GMT
Server: libwww-perl-daemon/6.12
Connection: close
```

Server Output:

```sh
GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection: TE, close
Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
TE: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.52

GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection: TE, close
Authorization: Basic dXNlcl9uYW1lOnNvbWVfcGFzcw==
Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
TE: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.52
```

**Notes:**

Example adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203964/lwpuseragent-http-basic-authentication).

Comment: Thanks for reply @ikegami. Could you provide an answer with a snippet of code?

Comment: I'm looking for some way to the `LWP::UserAgent` does this dirty job. Passing the `Authorization` hard coded is not an option.

Comment: @ikegami How can I do this without hard coding it? I updated the question to use `$ua->request($req);`